# Enabling php.ini for backward compatibility

Tags: php

From PHP 5.0.3 long predefined arrays such HTTP_GET_VARS got disabled by default.

Stackoverflow member Notinlist recently advised that for backward compatibility you can enable them in php.ini.... is this difficult to do and is it successful?

Comment: The question is: do you really need `HTTP_GET_VARS`? It does not make sense to enable it if you don't have code that relies on it. If its not much code, it might even make sense to adapt it.

Comment: I think this is the offending piece                          function getPostGetVars() {
  global $HTTP_POST_VARS,$HTTP_GET_VARS;
  foreach ($HTTP_POST_VARS as $key => $value) {
    global $$key;
    $$key = $value;
  }
  foreach ($HTTP_GET_VARS as $key => $value) {
    global $$key;
    $$key = $value;
  }
}

Comment: This looks like a workaround for `register_globals` and is a gaping security hole. You should really fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just google `allow HTTP_GET_VARS`? First result is very useful and even Google's excerpt tells you what to do

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php

> From PHP 5.0.3 long predefined arrays such HTTP_GET_VARS got disabled by default. For backward compatibility you can enable them in php.ini:
>
> register_long_arrays = On
>
> I sugget a big WARNING up there like that one with the
>   resister_globals.
>
> Anyway.. I cannot understand why they do such tings all the time.

Comment: It's important to remember that this feature has been REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0  (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-long-arrays)